# OAuth Invalid signature issue with Digg

Tags: authentication, digg, scribe

So I'm trying to authenticate my app to Digg using OAuth (and I'm totally not an OAuth expert).
I use the Scribe Java library.

I keep on getting the HTTP 401 Authorization Required. Inside the body of the response, it is a 5001 Invalid Signature Error.

I have read this [Digg Google Groups Thread](http://groups.google.com/group/diggapi/browse_thread/thread/f53e1932295cc002/)
and I didn't really understand. They say I should remove the method from the URL, but when I do this, I get the no Method provided error (or something like that).

Here is the dump of the communication : [on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/xbgdZikM)

Could you please help me finding the solution on how to get the request token?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to stop sending the method in the URL as a querystring parameter and do this instead:

```
request.addBodyParameter("method","oauth.getRequestToken");
```

Hope that works for you

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the request token request, and I do not have a reference over the Reference object.
Is there a way to get a reference over the Reference object?
Or to add a body parameter to that request (maybe using the Equalizers).
If not, I guess I will be looking at the source code of the library, in order to find a way to achieve this.

Comment: I have done the addBodyParameter, and it is still not working, I still have the same signature problem